# vertical break line an inline list

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to put the text in the **middle of vertical span**?

[image]

I want it to look like:

[image]

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.list-group-item2{
  border: none;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Adobe Arabic';
  font-size: 167%;
}
li a{
  color: #000000;
  background: transparent;
}
li a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fd5900;
}
.list-group-item2.sep{
  width: 1px;
  background: url('download.png')left center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 hidden-xs text-center">
      <ul class="list-group2 list-inline">
        <li class="list-group-item2">
          <a href="#">آرایشی</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item2 sep"></li>
        <li class="list-group-item2">
          <a href="#">رایحه</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item2 sep"></li>
        <li class="list-group-item2">
          <a href="#">شست و شو</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item2 sep"></li>
        <li class="list-group-item2">
          <a href="#">مو</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item2 sep"></li>
        <li class="list-group-item2">
          <a href="#">پوست</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item2 sep"></li>
        <li class="list-group-item2">
          <a href="#">آقایان</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item2 sep"></li>
        <li class="list-group-item2">
          <a href="#">خانم ها</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Usually this is managed by `lineheight`...perhaps you could demo this problem

Comment: its not working, both span and text had changed

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Put a Padding: 15px or so on the a html element! That's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the examples you've shown, it sounds like you want to have a navigation-style list with a vertical line breaking up each item, something like:

`item 1 | item 2 | item 3 | item 4`

You can achieve this with a combination of borders and `:last-of-type` to remove the final border at the end of your list.  See the following CodePen for example code:

http://codepen.io/rkieru/pen/JKyYpx

Comment: If you want to have the navigation justified rather than centered, you may need to adjust your code to rely on `flexbox`.